# How to Pass InfluxDB Token to Node-RED Nodes in Docker Compose Setup?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb, node-red

I'm using Docker Compose to set up Node-RED and InfluxDB, and I need Node-RED to interact with InfluxDB (using the dependency node-red-contrib-influxdb:0.6.1). InfluxDB 2.x requires a token for authorization and I'm not sure how to pass this token to the Node-RED nodes. The Node-RED is built using a custom Dockerfile that is presented here:

```
# Use the Node-RED base image
FROM nodered/node-red:latest
USER root

# Update the package list and install pandas and requests
RUN apk add --no-cache py3-pandas py3-pip py3-requests

USER node-red

COPY flows.json /data
COPY package.json /data

# Navigate to /data directory and Install the package.json dependencies
WORKDIR /data
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --no-update-notifier --no-fund --only=production
COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/node-red
EXPOSE 1880
```

Currently, when the containers are running, the InfluxDB nodes do not contain the token and hence are unauthorized.

I learned that node-red-contrib-influxdb does not support using tokens from environment variables directly in the InfluxDB node configuration. The token needs to be hardcoded into the InfluxDB node configuration in the Node-RED UI. However, this is not a desirable solution in my case.

Are any workarounds or solutions about this case ?

I attempted to pass the InfluxDB token to the Node-RED nodes via environment variables defined in my Docker Compose file.

I was expecting the InfluxDB nodes in Node-RED to be able to use the token specified in the environment variables for authentication with the InfluxDB service.

When the containers were up and running, the InfluxDB nodes did not contain the token and therefore were unauthorized to access the InfluxDB service. I checked the logs and found "Unauthorized" errors, indicating that the token was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as an environment variable to the `docker-compose.yml` then put `${env_var_name}` in the Node-RED flow config.

More details about how to reference environment variables in Node-RED can be found here: https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables

Comment: I'm currently using an influxdbout node in my Node-RED flow. However, in my flows.json file, there's no property where I can specify the InfluxDB token. Given this, could you please provide more details on how you suggest I pass the token from the environment variable to the InfluxDB node in Node-RED? Any specific examples or code snippets would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Environment variables work in all fields as they are handled by the platform, not the node. The only caveat is that they have to be the only thing in the field, they can not be used with anything else e.g. not `foo/${env_var}/bar